# Create File in non-existed Dir

Tags: php

I've ran into problem with Files and Dirs.
when I try to create File (after using file_exists()) and the dir is not exists it will raise an alarm saying can't open stream.
e.g. "/exist/exist/not-exist/not-exist/file.sh"
The best method i know is by **splitting** and **rejoin** the string/Path and then **create** it again(maybe with a loop if necessary).
is there any alternate way to achieve the **same** goal, cause this method has a lot of **issues** with "normal" Paths.

Comment: Simply create the folders and *then* upload the files into them?

Comment: @ObsidianAge e.g. file_put_contents("/nope/nope/exists/file","..."). This is the requested file. I don't even know if the string will even have dir(only FileName) or even root dir(starts with "/so/file"). if i try to split and create it it will take some resources (using a lot of "if",loop and so on). it will be better if there is "better" way

Comment: Maybe this is useful to you? http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php

Comment: Maybe this also: http://php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create full directory path using `mkdir` with recursive parameter:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php

```
mkdir(dirname('/exist/exist/not-exist/not-exist/file.sh'), $mode, true);
```

`dirname` is used to trim the file name.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php